# React add local state changes to browser history

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, browser-history

I'm new to react, and I'm wondering if there is a way to add local state changes to the browser history to allow users to use back browser button to navigate back. I know this could cause problems sometimes, but I'll do it just in some specific and managed cases.

In my real application I'm using react-router v4 and experimented with `history.push(location,state)` but it didn't worked out

Here is an example application on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/9oz34n30j4

In this application I'd like the user to be able to browse back with the browser button between status changes.

Is that possible in any way?

Thanks